# Angular Canvas is undefined inside event listener handler

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the canvas inside angular. I am getting the canvas via ViewChild. The code below shows how/where i get the error. First i had arrow functions where i add an event listener (which worked fine), but since i now also need to remove the event listeners under a certain circumstance, i had to create functions for event handlers. And once i added the functions for event handlers, it stopped working. It started saying that use `this.context` and `this.canvas` are undefined.

One of the errors:

`core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'beginPath')`

```
@ViewChild('canvas', { static: false }) canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.refresh();
}

private refresh(): void {
  this.blahblah.blah().subscribe(() => {
    this.initCanvas();
  });
}

private initCanvas(): void {
  if(something) {
    this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUpEvent);
    this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener(
      'mousedown',
      this.mouseDownEvent
    );
    this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener(
      'mousemove',
      this.mouseMoveEvent
    );
  } else {
    this.canvas.nativeElement.removeEventListener(
      'mouseup',
      this.mouseUpEvent
    );
    this.canvas.nativeElement.removeEventListener(
      'mousedown',
      this.mouseDownEvent
    );
    this.canvas.nativeElement.removeEventListener(
      'mousemove',
      this.mouseMoveEvent
    );  
  }
}

public mouseUpEvent(): void {
  this.drawing = false;
  this.context.beginPath();
}

public mouseDownEvent(): void {
  this.drawing = true;
}

public mouseMoveEvent(event: any): void {
  console.log(this.canvas); //UNDEFINED
  if (!this.drawing) return;

  const rect = this.canvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = Math.round(
    ((event.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left)) *
      this.canvas.nativeElement.width
  );
  const y = Math.round(
    ((event.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top)) *
      this.canvas.nativeElement.height
  );

  this.context.lineWidth = 5;
  this.context.lineCap = 'round';

  this.context.lineTo(x, y);
  this.context.stroke();
  this.context.beginPath();
  this.context.moveTo(x, y);
}
```

Comment: The same thing applies here, you need to use arrow function or binding `this`, as otherwise you loose the context of `this`. So, use arrow function or `bind(this)`, e.g `this.mouseUpEvent.bind(this)`

Comment: have you tried setting `@ViewChild('sidenav', { static: true })`

Comment: @AJT82 has answered my question, i can't accept a comment though.